# SVG line not getting rendered properly in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, svg, itext, batik

I am using iText and some SVG rendering library.

I want to render a SVG image to PDF. I am using following code to do that. Now the problem is I am giving an area chart SVG to it, it is not rendering line properly. Attaching screenshots.

Following classes has been used:

```
import org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.DocumentLoader;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgent;
import org.apache.batik.bridge.UserAgentAdapter;
import org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SAXSVGDocumentFactory;
import org.apache.batik.gvt.GraphicsNode;
import org.apache.batik.util.XMLResourceDescriptor;
import org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument;
```

and here the cop snippet:

```
    String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
    factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);

    UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgentAdapter();
    DocumentLoader loader = new DocumentLoader(userAgent);
    ctx = new BridgeContext(userAgent, loader);
    ctx.setDynamicState(BridgeContext.DYNAMIC);

    builder = new GVTBuilder();

    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();


    PdfTemplate chartImageTemplate = cb.createTemplate(1000, 1000);


    SVGDocument svgDoc=null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(chartImage.getBytes());
        svgDoc = factory.createSVGDocument("", in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        GraphicsNode mapGraphics = builder.build(ctx, svgDoc);

        DefaultFontMapper mapper = new DefaultFontMapper();
        PdfGraphics2D g2 = (PdfGraphics2D)cb.createGraphics(1000, 500, mapper);
        Graphics2D g2d = g2;
        mapGraphics.paint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();

        cb.addTemplate(chartImageTemplate, 0, 0);
        return mapGraphics.getGeometryBounds().getHeight();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

***You can find SVG here:***
http://speedy.sh/xvDp8/demo.svg

***Actual SVG:***
 [image]

***Rendered PDF***

[image]

Comment: I am the Lowagie from com.lowagie. If you go to http://lowagie.com, it is me you'll see. So I hope that you believe me when I say that there is no such thing as iText version 4.2 as I have never made an official iText 4.2 release. If you have a 4.2 version, you are using an *unofficial* version and you should not expect any help.

Comment: Moreover, iText *does not* render SVG. You are using a third party tool to create a `GraphicsNode` object (and `GraphicsNode` is *not* an iText class). This third party object paints itself to a `PdfGraphics2D` object. `PdfGraphics2D` is an iText implementation of the Java `Graphics2D` class. If `GraphicsNode` doesn't render some content to this `Graphics2D` implementation, then you are facing a problem with your SVG rendering software, *not* with iText.

Comment: I have updated your question. Please replace *some SVG rendering library* with the actual name of that library.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. I have updated my question. I am using apache batik for it.

Comment: Thanks, I also see that you've added the batik tag. That should result in some answers. Did you also try using Salamander: https://svgsalamander.java.net/