# Svg Image is not properly render in the pdf

Tags: java, itext7

[[image: output image]]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYEPw.png)[[image: this is the output i get[![And the expected output is like this image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Dd5H.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Tuj.png)

Here is my code to add svg image in the pdf using itext 7.1.3 and also using SVGConventer.The image not properly rendered, i am not able understand where and what is the problem?     Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

```
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("/home/users/Documents/pdf/new.pdf"));
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
URL svgUrl = new File(svg).toURI().toURL();
doc.add(new Paragraph("new pikachu"));                      
Image image = SvgConverter.convertToImage(svgUrl.openStream(), pdfDoc);                 
doc.add(image);
doc.close();
```

Comment: First step would be to find out if the conversion to an image is the problem or the embedding in the PDF document.

Comment: The problem is only in the image. The 1st image is the output image and the 2nd image is the expected output.(Both images in svg format)

Comment: Save image into some PNG file fist to check whether problem in saving image into PDF or in rendering from vector.    `File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);`

Comment: iText7 still does not have full SVG support

Comment: @Victor Gubin - Thanks, The png images renders properly but the problem is in svg image only

Comment: @Alexey Subach - Thanks , Then the issues has no solutions ?

Comment: The solution is either wait for iText to better support SVG, or make a pull request with fixes for the problems you have, or use other tools to convert SVG to PDF :)

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest me then any other way using itext7 to convert SVG to PDF :)

Comment: Is there any other libary other than SVGConveter in itext7 for SVG image in PDF?

Comment: @Yahini priya Raja. Take a look into comments at for the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889780/svg-line-not-getting-rendered-properly-in-pdf

Comment: And [batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) can be used to render SVG into a Java2D. So you can draw into com.itextpdf.awt.PdfGraphics2D from batik.

Comment: @Victor Gubin -Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408042/vector-graphics-in-itext-pdf ]

i tried the example of batik library as done as in this link.
 For me **PDFTemplate and PDFContentByte** it doesn't support in itext7, what to do ? any suggestions? Thanks in advance